# 'Ember generate resource' command end up adding this.route() to router.js

Tags: javascript, ember.js, ember-cli, ember-router

I am going through a tutorial on ember-cli and faced some strange behavior: 
To generate a new resource named 'friends' I am running an ember-cli command:

```
$ ember generate resource friends
```

And the generator creates all the required files, plus in the app/router.js it adds the following:

```
...
Router.map(function() {
  this.route('friends');
});
...
```

and I expect it to create (and this is mentioned in the tutorial):

```
  this.resource('friends', function(){ });
```

instead of

```
  this.route('friends');
```

So i can not understand, what am I doing wrong? Or maybe something changed in ember-cli routes/resources generator since this tutorial were released and this behavior is now normal?

Thanks in advance,
Gleb.

Comment: Which version of ember-cli are you using. I know in later versions they have replaced `this.resource('thing')` with `this.route('thing', { resetNamespace: true })`

Comment: Resource is deprecated and no longer in use, routes can be nested.

Comment: @tomasbasham Ok, i discovered that my version was 0.2.7 and the most recent is 1.13.1. Still after updating I'm getting the same result. Guess resources are no longer used.

Comment: @Kitler Thank you, that's something i thought, but I could not find any confirmation anywhere. Now i can continue without worries.

Comment: When in doubt check the [source](https://github.com/ember-cli/ember-cli/commit/734d4c76911f6d190c6d668de69e81df86a1d48d)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Prior to ember 1.7 resources were used due to their ability to reset the namespace and nest routes, routes could not be nested at the time.

Since ember 1.7+ routes can be nested and you can reset the namespace by setting `this.route('my-route', { path: '/mypath', resetNamespace: true } function() {});`

The [blueprint](https://github.com/ember-cli/ember-cli/commit/734d4c76911f6d190c6d668de69e81df86a1d48d) you are using was last modified on april 24 to reflect the deprecation and use routes instead of resources.

For more information give the following [article](https://gist.github.com/samselikoff/1d7300ce59d216fdaf97) a read.